# How do I blacklist a jwt refresh token stored in redis database in a node application?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, redis, jwt

I am building a blog application using node, mongodb and reactjs. I have jwt system working, when a user logs-in, the user generates both accessToken and refresh_Token. The refresh_Token is stored in redis database. The refresh_Token last for 30 days while the accessToken last for 15 minutes.
I created a route that generates new refresh_Token and accessToken once the accessToken expires in 15 minutes. However, I have been searching online on how to blacklist the previously generated refresh_Token which I stored in redis databas each time new acceesToken and refresh_Token are generated. Can anyone help me with the right codes to write for this to work? I will like to implement the blacklist on logout and each time the new set of accessToken and refresh_Tokens are regenerated. Here are my codes so far:

```
//login

const login = async (req, res) =>{
 try {
    const user = await User.findOne({username: req.body.username})
    let passValidate
    if(user) {
        passValidate = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password)
    }

    if(!user || !passValidate || user.role === "admin") {
        res.status(400).json("Wrong credentials");
    } else {
        const {password, ...others} = user._doc;

        //generate access token
        const token = jwt.sign({userId: user._id, username:user.username, role: user.role}, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
            expiresIn: process.env.JWT_LIFETIME});

        //generate refresh token
         const refresh_Token = jwt.sign({userId: user._id, username:user.username, role: user.role}, process.env.Refresh_Secret);
         //check refreshtoken in redis database

         await client.get(user._id.toString(), (err, data)=>{
            if(err) throw err;

        //set refresh token in redis database
            client.set(user._id.toString(), JSON.stringify(refresh_Token));
         }); 
        res.status(200).json({user: {username: user.username, userId: user._id}, token, refresh_Token})
    } 
} catch(err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
}
}
```

Codes to verify access token:

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken")

 const verify = (req, res, next) =>{
 const authHeader = req.headers.authorization;
 if(authHeader){
    const token = authHeader.split(" ")[1];

    jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET, (err, user)=>{
        if(err){
            return res.status(403).json("Token is not valid");
        }
        req.user = user;
        next();
    });
} else{
    res.status(401).json("You're not authenticated")
}
}
```

module.exports = verify

Login route:

```
const {login} = require('../controller/auth');
router.post('/login', login);
```

Code to verify refresh_Token

```
const redis_client = require('../reditConnect');

const refreshTokenverify = async (req, res, next) =>{
//check for the header

const authHeader = req.headers.authorization;
if(!authHeader || !authHeader.startsWith('bearer')){
   return res.status(401).json({message: "Your session is not valid"})
};

const token = authHeader.split(' ')[1];

try{
const payload = jwt.verify(token, process.env.Refresh_Secret)
//attach the user to the job routes
req.user = {userId:payload.userId};

  await redis_client.get(payload.userId.toString(), (err, data)=>{
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        };
        if(data === null) return res.status(401).json({message: "Token not found in  database"});
        if(JSON.parse(data).refresh_Token != token) return res.status(401).json({message:  "Invaid request"});
 })

 next()
}catch(err){
    console.log(err)
    return res.status(401).json({message: "Invalid token"})
    
}
};
```

Codes to regenerate new accessToken and refresh_Token each time access token expires every 15 minutes:

```
const regenrateToken = async (req, res)=>{
const userId = req.user.userId


 const token = jwt.sign({userId: req.user.userId, username:req.user.username, role:  req.user.role}, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
 expiresIn: process.env.JWT_LIFETIME});

 refresh_Token = jwt.sign({userId: req.user.userId}, process.env.Refresh_Secret);

await redis_client.set(req.user.userId.toString(), JSON.stringify(refresh_Token))
 res.status(401).json({data: {token, refresh_Token}});

 return refresh_Token
 //console.log(req)
  
};
```

Refresh_Token route:

```
const {refreshTokenverify, regenrateToken} = require('../middleware/refreshTokenVerify');

router.post('/refresh', refreshTokenverify, regenrateToken);
```

I'm yet to write for codes for logout. I want to sort to be able to blacklist the previously used refresh_Tokens because they are still valid for 30 days. So, how do I go about that?

Comment: Remember, that people here will help you when you're stuck but they won't write code for you. To guide you a bit, what you want is to `set` an entry in Redis with the old refresh token inside the methods which generate new refresh tokens and which logout the user (I would use the user ID as the key, and add the RT to a list in the JSON you save to Redis). Then, whenever you verify the RT you should read that list from Redis and check whether the RT is on that list.

Comment: have you found your aswer by this point? would be nice to know

Comment: Hello, I completely changed the method that I used and it is working now.

Comment: What I did was that user cant generate a new refresh Token except it is found in redis database. And I also didnt change refresh token each time new access token is regenerated. This will enable me to track the refresh token that gets compromised easily and delete it from the database. Since user can't create a new access token if the refresh token used to regenerate the access token is not found in redis database, if a refresh token gets compromised and I delete it from redis, that refresh token becomes useless.